# Passcode ViewController Presentation from Modal View

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm implementing a Passcode feature in my iPhone app which has a UITabBarController as a root view controller.  I have everything working great in most situations, by displaying a modal Passcode ViewController from the tabBarController when the app goes into the background, like so:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kPasscodeStringKey]) {

        PasscodeEntryVC *passcodeView = [[PasscodeEntryVC alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:passcodeView];
        [tabBarController presentModalViewController:nav animated:NO];
    }
}
```

My problem comes when the app is already displaying a modal view controller when it enters the background.  Then, no passcode view appears.  What would be the correct way to do this?  Instead of just sending the message to the tabBarController to present the view, should I be checking first to see what the current view is, then have that present the passcode? If so, how is this done?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First - you are leaking memory because you do not `release` your `passcodeView` and navigation controller `nav`.

Second - you could keep a simple `BOOL` variable that is updated whenever a modal view is presented or dismissed. If there is a modal view, just call `dismissModalViewController:animated:` in your `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method.

You could also check the frontmost view controller with `[self.navigationController.topViewController class]`, but I have found this to be unreliable.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using ARC, so the memory is fine.  In the future I'll post code with retain/release for clarity.
What If I wanted to display the modal passcode view on top of the existing modal view?  Any quick way to get a reference to the current view controller, be it modal or not?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to ensure that any views I have that may present a modal view controller to dismiss the modal view controller whenever it is sent the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification, while over in my app delegate, I set it up exactly like yours.

One caveat though, is that whenever you dismiss the said modal view controllers, you need to ensure that you dismiss them with `animated:` set to `NO` before presenting your passcode view controller.